# Can i give mapped memory to malloc?

Tags: memory, posix, glibc, mmap

Say I have a big block of mapped memory I finished using. It came from `mmap`ing anonymous memory or using `MAP_PRIVATE`. I could `munmap` it, then have `malloc` `mmap` again the next time I make a big enough allocation.

Could I instead give the memory to `malloc` directly? Could I say "Hey `malloc`, here's an address range I mapped. Go use it for heap space. Feel free to `mprotect`, `mremap`, or even `munmap` it as you wish."?

I'm using glibc on linux.

Comment: Did you look at https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals?

Comment: I did look there. I also found `malloc_get_state`, `malloc_get_state`, and `mallopt`, but none seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glibc malloc calls `__morecore` (a function pointer) to obtain more memory. See `<malloc.h>`.  However, this will not work in general because the implementation assumes that the function behaves like `sbrk` and returns memory from a single, larger memory region.  In practice, with glibc malloc, the only realistic way to make memory available for reuse by malloc is calling `munmap`.

Other malloc implementations allow donating memory (in some cases as internal interfaces).  For example, musl's malloc has a function called `__malloc_donate` which should do what you are asking for.